# Jupyter lab multiple notebooks with daemon application

Tags: nginx, server, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm planning to create a custom Jupyter kernel which runs external daemon app(Verum Dezyne) and displays stuff at localhost/xxx0-xxx4 within the notebook cells.
Looks like [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xmF0.png)

I managed to create a single jupyter lab instance but I have no idea how to make it available for multiple external users. Ideally each user has its own daemon instance to simulate Dezyne model.

I want to deploy it at DigitalOcean droplet, my first idea is to use nginx with multiple docker instances but maybe it's an overkill

Any suggestions?

Thanks